arcpy.ListRaster() returns all layer names in uppercase
This is an issue a coworker has encountered and i've diagnosed. We were trying to programmatically rename layers in an Enterprise GDB by replacing two different substrings, but it wasn't working, and this appears to be why.
Here's our code:
input_workspace = r'path'
arcpy.env.workspace = input_workspace

removeString1 = "OldName1"
addString1 = "NewName1"
removeString2 = "OldName2"
addString2 = "NewName2"
input_ras = arcpy.ListRasters(f'*{removeString1}*')

for raster in input_ras:
    print(f"Returned raster name: {raster}")
    newName = raster.replace(removeString1.upper(), addString1).replace(removeString2.upper(), addString2)
    print(f"New name: {newName}")
    arcpy.management.Rename(raster, newName)
    print(f"\tReplaced '{raster}' with {newName}")

The addition of .upper() is telling here, this was the only way to get the code to actually find matches, as the list returned by ListRasters() is fully capitalised, when the layers names are not. ListRaster() seems to read them that way as it finds the layers matching the keyword fin, but returns them modified. The issue here is that the remaining parts of the layer names have different combinations of letters and other components that use uppercase in varied ways, so there's no straightforward way to convert them all back while also achieving the above. So we're left with layer names where everything except what is modified in this code is in uppercase.
I've tried using arcpy.da.Walk() but it's the same issue.
Is there a way to derive a list of rasters in an Enterprise GDB while retaining their original capitalisation?

May be its an issue with how you have configured your enterprise database as this problem does not occur with a file geodatabase?

What RDBMS platform is your enterprise database using?  Eg, Oracle, MS SQL, Postgres, etc

@Son of a Beach it's in Oracle

Looks like Oracle sticks to strict ANSI SQL and converts all table names to uppercase, unless you explicitly tell it otherwise (by using double-quotes at the SQL level).
See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342165/how-i-can-create-a-table-with-oracle-but-with-small-characters
This applies to table names in SQL to create the tables (so tables will actually be created with all uppercase, unless you explicitly tell it not to) and in SQL to query tables (so it’s a good idea to let it stick to uppercase, unless you are sure everyone is going to remember to use explicit cases in every SQL statement later on).
